# Looking for Specific (WxH) Sized Monitor

Tags: desktop, monitors

Background: I am working on rebuilding my desk, the glass top broke, and finally got around to ordering and obtaining my glass top for the desk. As a hardware and tech enthusiast, I am going to make this desk host a large portion of my wires for about 3 computers which will be in close proximity of the desk. It's a decent sized desk, and I have big plans for it.

My desk top will be glass, so I plan on using this to my advantage by placing a monitor directly under the glass on the right side of my desk. This allows me to save space and have the monitor to stay clean. The problem is the space is limited so the max height is 11" and max length is around 17.5" of what can fit inside.

The dimensions of the space is 17.5" x 11" and here is a pic of the area (warning, tech support gore):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AcnV.jpg

Anything helps, but I do NOT want a USB monitor. I already have found one that is (USB 3.0) 15.6" and the problem is it not IPS and is a bad screen in terms of brightness and resolution (plus it uses CPU). You can literally not view it at another (other than level eye to eye) angle.

HDMI/DisplayPort input is ideal and close to if not higher than 1080p. IPS is ideal as well for viewing angles (unless any of you can give me an alternative suggestion), which is a monitor feature allowing one to view from any angle without fade.

TL;DR I need a 1080p monitor within 17.5" x 11"

**EDIT :**
I have successfully put on the new glass top for my desk (which originally broke) so progress has been made! I will have to do some tweaks to the frame of the desk to make sure it can optimally support weight. Here is a picture of the glass top if curious: (will edit in later)

@johnkieran (In response to your answer): I think of the two monitors suggested, the ViewSonic VA2055SM seems to definitely be superior... The 1080p and the "SuperClear MVA panel technology" or "proprietary panel technology" seems to definitely rival the IPS. If not, I can just return the monitor after testing it (I will update this post if it does not work). I think this also may mean ViewSonic will be best for this size range as IPS is extremely rare at this size, especially while keeping the 1080p resolution.

Next current question would be reducing the size of the monitor to fit the 17.5" x 11" space under the glass. I need to find a guide to remove bevel/frame of the monitor. I still am not sure what would be ideal for reframing it... True, I may be able to use a wide variety of materials to reframe it, but the question is what would be ideal/optimal to use and how to apply it. I am wondering if some form of cloth, but I would have no idea how to apply it. I want the LCD to be fully protected, regardless of the glass (desk).

Some other monitors I have found that are close or noteworthy:

Dell D2015HM 19.5" Screen LED-Lit Monitor (Discontinued by Manufacturer) [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B012AQIEVI/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awd_mCAdxb4MPA86Z](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012AQIEVI)

HP Pavilion 21.5-Inch IPS LED HDMI VGA Monitor [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B015WCV70W/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awd_VCAdxbEDNVQSC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015WCV70W)

19" LED TV [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00LUCVWGS/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awd_mDAdxbAYYHNMC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LUCVWGS)

SuperSonic 19-Inch 1080p LED Widescreen HDTV with Built-in DVD Player, HDMI Input, AC/DC Compatible (SC-1912) [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0057IM9EU/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awd_EDAdxbFY1Q2B7](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057IM9EU)

Thanks all! I hope to hear some more thoughts!

Answer (score 4):

Your size requirements are a very odd size for monitors, so I don't think you'll find one exactly fitting your needs (short of having one custom made). That said, I have found some that are very close.

The [ViewSonic VA2055SM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010BEDSE4):
- 8.3 x 18.6 x 11.3 inches
- full HD 1080p, 20" diagonal
- Currently $84.99, *$171 regular*
- DVI & VGA (only the one with built-in speakers has DVI)
Apparently, ViewSonic also has a proprietary panel technology:
**"With SuperClear MVA panel technology, this monitor delivers the same image quality whether you are looking at the screen from above, below, the front, or the side."**

The [ASUS VE208T](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0045JFTXU):
- 11 3/8 inches high 18 3/4 inches wide (without stand)
- currently $112.99, *$124.99 regular*
- 20" diagonal, 1600x900 resolution
- According to reviews, good viewing angle
- DVI Input

Comment: These are extremely close to my requirements. I am wondering if it is out of the question to sand (as painful as that sounds) the sides.. Thank you for this response. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You could maybe try to remove the LCD from the plastic frame and make your own, or buy one that suits your needs, because I'm sure the LCD panel itself would fit very neatly inside your requested space.

Comment: @HenryL, if they're measuring the diagonal the usual way (diagonal measure of the actual panel), the ViewSonic monitor is 17.4"x9.8" with the frame removed.  If they're measuring the diagonal of the viewable area, it's somewhat larger.

Comment: Huh. Thanks you two. I didn't know removing the plastic frame was an option, but if it is that would definitely fix the problem. @johnkieran I'm not sure what material I would use to "reframe" the LCD. Where would I even start with that? Nonetheless, Obviously removing the frame voids warranty which is fine, but lol

Comment: @HenryL reframe with anything you want, as long as it's non-conductive. As for that ViewSonic panel, that's a proprietary spin on Vertical Alignment panels, which are somewhere in-between TN and IPS but still have pretty good angles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display#Vertical_alignment_.28VA.29